# CSS file load time peformance issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to speed up my website, and looks like loading the following two files pretty much consuming the time.

volumewatchers.com/?itx=css&ver=3.5.1
volumewatchers.com/?itx=js&ver=3.5.1

These are very small files and I don't see a reason for almost 2 sec for them to load.

Pingdom report:
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cdpj8h/http://volumewatchers.com/

It looks like the itx wordpress theme is trying load those file dynamically through wp-enqueue . As the template is pretty much set, i can hard code those file in the  section. Could  someone advise me, how to tweak this code and hard code these file? I did a view source and created a .CSS file. But, it didn't help much.

Here is header.php code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>"  />
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> latest post RSS" href="<?php echo itx_get_option('links','rss') ?>" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?> latest comment RSS" href="<?php echo itx_get_option('links','crss') ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/ie6.css">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" />  
<?php
    if (is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' )) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    if (is_active_widget(false,false,'itx_tabbed_sidebar')||!is_active_sidebar(1)) wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
    if ( itx_get_option('misc','nohover') == 0 ) wp_enqueue_script('jquery-color');
    wp_enqueue_script('itx',get_bloginfo('url').'/?itx=js');
    wp_enqueue_style('itx',get_bloginfo('url').itx_preview_vars('css'));
    wp_head();
?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered merging your files? I noticed you use 4 stylesheets (+ some inline styles) and 19 javascript files. If you could merge these into one (minified) css and as little as possible (minified) js files, you would probably gain some speed. Typically it takes longer for the browser to request a file then to download some extra bytes, so it is good practice to make as little requests as possible.

Comment: Many of the JS and CSS are from the various plugins. I am using cloudflare and W3 Total cache.So, as much as minification and caching already done. So, not sure I can combine them without touching core code of the plugins/theme. If I get these two files to loaded in no time, I believe the performance will go down less than 3 sec Which is my goal until I get a moden/light weighted theme.